# How to install Android Virtual Device manager and intel system image with sdkmanager

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to create android emulator with only command line tools.

I've downloaded sdkmanager and successfully installed "platform"

`sdkmanager "platforms;android-25"`. But I can't install system image, because
`sdkmanager --list` gives this

```
system-images;a...ult;armeabi-v7a | 4            | ARM EABI v7a System Image        
  system-images;a...-10;default;x86 | 4            | Intel x86 Atom System Image      
  system-images;a...pis;armeabi-v7a | 5            | Google APIs ARM EABI v7a Syste...
```

Someone decided that I don't need to see full names of packages that I want to install. But at the same time when trying to install something from this list `sdkmanager` seems to think otherwise.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42521077/624706

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the comment you received, you could also use the "android" script located in the tools folder, here is the output on my machine (I have truncated the output):

```
[user@pc:~/sdk/tools]
└─ $ ▶ ./android list sdk

******************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*********************************************************************
"android" SDK commands can be translated to sdkmanager commands on a 
best-effort basis.
Continue? (This prompt can be suppressed with the --use-sdk-wrapper 
command-line argument
or by setting the USE_SDK_WRAPPER environment variable) [y/N]: y
Running /home/user/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list --verbose

Info: Parsing /home/user/sdk/build-tools/24.0.3/package.xml
Info: Parsing /home/user/sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/package.xml
Info: Parsing /home/user/sdk/emulator/package.xml
Info: Parsing /home/user/sdk/patcher/v4/package.xml
...
Info: Parsing /home/user/sdk/tools/package.xml
Warning: File /home/user/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Installed packages:
--------------------------------------
build-tools;24.0.3
    Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 24.0.3
    Version:            24.0.3
    Installed Location: /home/user/sdk/build-tools/24.0.3

build-tools;25.0.2
    Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2
    Version:            25.0.2
    Installed Location: /home/user/sdk/build-tools/25.0.2
...
system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86_64
    Description:        Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image
    Version:            4
```

To make sure we are on the same page:

- I have downloaded the file tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip from [this site](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads). Unzipped it into ~/sdk
- I have this packages installed using the tools/sdkmanager:

build-tools;24.0.3
build-tools/25.0.2
emulator                          | 26.0.0
platform-tools                    | 25.0.4
platforms;android-24              | 2
platforms;android-25              | 3
tools                             | 26.0.1

Edit: After reading the whole command output, it turns out that you could also use the --verbose flag:

```
[user@pc:~/sdk/tools]
└─ $ ▶ sdkmanager --list --verbose
```